# Facing issue while executing parallel testing (Firefox and chrome) with TestNG,

Tags: java, testng

During execution, web-drivers get initialized and steps are executed correctly in two different threads.

When one thread completes its execution, the next thread stops its execution without throwing any errors. 
I am not using static variables and 
Please help me in fixing the same and my xml looks like this..

```
<test name="chrometest">
    <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
    <classes>
        <class name="AutomationEngine.Driver" />
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="test2">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
    <classes>
        <class name="AutomationEngine.Driver" />

    </classes>
</test>
```

`

Driver instantiation in Before method and driver.quit in after method

public class TestBase
{
    private WebDriver driver;

```
long firefox, chrome;

@Parameters("browser")
@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest(final String browser) throws Exception
{

    if (browser.equals("firefox"))
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
                "E:\\old laptop\\workspace\\mobile-automation\\TestMyBlood\\References\\geckodriver.exe");

    }
    else
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\Users\\divya\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

    }
    setUpWebDriver(browser);
}

private synchronized void setUpWebDriver(final String browser)
{
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = browser.equals("firefox") ? DesiredCapabilities.firefox()
            : DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capabilities.setBrowserName(browser);
    // capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WIN10);
    driver = browser.equals("firefox") ? new FirefoxDriver(capabilities)
            : new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    printer("beforeTest : " + browser);
    Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
    if (browser.equals("firefox"))
    {

        firefox = t.getId();
    }
    else
    {
        chrome = t.getId();

    }
}

@AfterTest
public synchronized void AfterTest() throws Exception
{
    if ((Thread.currentThread().getId()) == (chrome))
    {
        System.out.println("closing driver is chrome");
        driver.quit();
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("closing driver is firefox");
        driver.quit();
    }

}

public WebDriver getDriver()
{
    return driver;
}

protected void printer(final String methodName)
{
    final String msg = String.format("%s() is running on Thread id [%d]", methodName,
            Thread.currentThread().getId());
    System.err.println("[DEBUGGER] :" + methodName);
    System.out.println(msg);

}
```

}

Comment: First of all please provide some code examples, testNg suite files etc. This is impossible to answer with this small portion of information.

Comment: What drivers, which version of browser, some code example, testsuite.xml example and so on.

Comment: Updated the testsuite xml

Comment: plz provide script

Comment: Also confirm, "AutomationEngine" is your package name for your exactable class name as "Driver" ? should be <class name="packagename.target class name" >

Comment: yes Automation engine is the package name for the class Driver